# Power BI: Sum column distinct per another particular column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am building a report about costumer complaints.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6kyo.jpg)

Now I am trying to get the right sum for "Reklamationskosten" (cost).
The correct answer is: 113 EUR.

The formula should do (in words):
"Sum the 'Reklamationskosten' for each 'Rekl. ID' but only once for each 'Reklamationskosten Art' "

Sure there is a way to do this in DAX but I cannot find out how.
Thank you all very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can create a measure using `SUMX` that iterates over a summarized table:

```
Reklamationskosten Measure = 
SUMX ( 
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Rekl. ID],
        'Table'[Reklamationskosten Art],
        'Table'[Reklamationskosten]
    ),
    [Reklamationskosten]
)
```

This assumes that each "corresponding" row of `Reklamationskosten Art` has the same value of `Reklamationskosten` - else the values will be duplicated. You can alter the functionality of this by introducing aggregators handling multiple values using e.g. `MAX`:

```
Reklamationskosten Measure (Agg) = 
SUMX ( 
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Rekl. ID],
        'Table'[Reklamationskosten Art],
        "Reklamationskosten", MAX ( 'Table'[Reklamationskosten] )
    ),
    [Reklamationskosten]
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Marcus and Dharman!
I was thinking about this for 6 weeks now and it took you 17 minutes so solve my problem :)
Works perfectly.